# MySQL query for remove items from database, but keep 1 single row per day

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a mysql database with multiple rows. Every night I will delete all rows EXCEPT 1 row per day.

As example:

```
2019-01-01 15:23:24 | 1.5
2019-01-01 13:22:24 | 1.73
2019-01-01 12:26:24 | 1.6
2019-01-02 11:21:25 | 1.25
```

will be:

```
2019-01-01 15:23:24 | 1.5
2019-01-02 11:21:25 | 1.25
```

Can I do this with 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the maximum date for each day:

```
delete from tablename
where date not in (
  select * from (
    select max(date) 
    from tablename
    group by date(date)
  ) g  
);
```

The subquery returns the last value of each day, so every other row is deleted.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oxgF9LAJV6Md6BuxiNmo2x/1).
Results:

```
| date                | col  |
| ------------------- | ---- |
| 2019-01-01 15:23:24 | 1.5  |
| 2019-01-02 11:21:25 | 1.25 |
```